# where does SVG code go in relation to html, body, header, javascript, css

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

can you please give me a structure like this:

```
<html><body><svg></svg><javascript>..............</html> ??
```

i am having A LOT of trouble adding css and javascript to an SVG file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.0"
   width="958.69"
   height="592.78998"
   id="svg2275"
   sodipodi:version="0.32"
   inkscape:version="0.46"
   sodipodi:docname="Map of USA with state names.svg"
   sodipodi:docbase="C:\temp\webdesign"
   inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape">


    <script type="text/ecmascript">
    <![CDATA[

      function showRectArea(state) {
        var x = new Object();
        x["HI"] = "you clicked hawaii";
        x["CT"] = "you clicked CT";
        alert(x[state]);
      }

      var tooltip=function(){
      var id = 'tt';
 var top = 3;
 var left = 3;
 var maxw = 300;
 var speed = 10;
 var timer = 20;
 var endalpha = 95;
 var alpha = 0;
 var tt,t,c,b,h;
 var ie = document.all ? true : false;
 return{
  show:function(v,w){
   if(tt == null){
    tt = document.createElement('div');
    tt.setAttribute('id',id);
    t = document.createElement('div');
    t.setAttribute('id',id + 'top');
    c = document.createElement('div');
    c.setAttribute('id',id + 'cont');
    b = document.createElement('div');
    b.setAttribute('id',id + 'bot');
    tt.appendChild(t);
    tt.appendChild(c);
    tt.appendChild(b);
    document.body.appendChild(tt);
    tt.style.opacity = 0;
    tt.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=0)';
    document.onmousemove = this.pos;
   }
   tt.style.display = 'block';
   c.innerHTML = v;
   tt.style.width = w ? w + 'px' : 'auto';
   if(!w && ie){
    t.style.display = 'none';
    b.style.display = 'none';
    tt.style.width = tt.offsetWidth;
    t.style.display = 'block';
    b.style.display = 'block';
   }
  if(tt.offsetWidth > maxw){tt.style.width = maxw + 'px'}
  h = parseInt(tt.offsetHeight) + top;
  clearInterval(tt.timer);
  tt.timer = setInterval(function(){tooltip.fade(1)},timer);
  },
  pos:function(e){
   var u = ie ? event.clientY + document.documentElement.scrollTop : e.pageY;
   var l = ie ? event.clientX + document.documentElement.scrollLeft : e.pageX;
   tt.style.top = (u - h) + 'px';
   tt.style.left = (l + left) + 'px';
  },
  fade:function(d){
   var a = alpha;
   if((a != endalpha && d == 1) || (a != 0 && d == -1)){
    var i = speed;
   if(endalpha - a < speed && d == 1){
    i = endalpha - a;
   }else if(alpha < speed && d == -1){
     i = a;
   }
   alpha = a + (i * d);
   tt.style.opacity = alpha * .01;
etc
etc
etc
etc
```

Comment: What language are you using? XHTML 1.0? HTML 5? (They have different methods for embedding SVG, and neither is well supported among browsers)

Comment: david, i dont know. i dont think it matters to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this for some basic background on svg: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp regarding the embed, object and iframe tags within an HTML page.

As for the final result of what you are attempting...that remains to be isolated, presented and thus resolved!

Answer (score 1):

Last time I used SVG was for a graph generator on an embedded system, and it had the graph as a separate SVG object.  Also, I was using XHTML 1.0.

```
Content-Type: image/svg+xml
// Some other HTTP headers here...

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 99.5 99.5">
<!-- svg stuff goes here -->
</svg>
```

(No, I didn't hardcode the 100x100 dimensions; I just filled those in for this example.)